# Google Translate language when click Flag icons in js not working whole site

Tags: javascript

I used google translate customise when to click a flag icon, using below Url,
[Reference Url](http://www.freshcodehub.com/Article/26/implementing-google-translate-with-custom-flag-icons)

It's worked But when redirecting Next page it's not showing the translated language, It's showing default language English why? Once User translate Spanish means it's translated language my whole site

Comment: It converts only the page you are on. you need to store language related information into database or browser cache or temp data and when you redirect to the next page you should check for existing information (language related information) and if you can find stored data use it and convert page.

Comment: Thanx for your response, is there any option to trigger goog-te-combo?